# How does Ethan know that Phelps is the mole?

Tags: plot-explanation, mission-impossible, mission-impossible-1996

During a scene in the movie, while Ethan is looking at a bible with a Chicago stamp on it, he has a revelation that Jim Phelps is actually the mole.

How did he come to this idea and how did the Chicago stamp lead him to this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, the bible is not just from Chicago, but especially from the *Drake Hotel* in Chicago, where Jim lived as he said earlier. This is quite a coincidence, considering that Jim wouldn't have any reason to steal a bible from the hotel. On the other hand *Job* surely needs a bible for the communication cypher with *Max* based on bible quotes.

So it is the mere coincidence, that the bible is exactly from the hotel *Jim* lived in and he probably took it with him. Together with the fact that he surprisingly survived it is a strong indication of *Jim* being the traitor.

I'm not sure he immediately believed *Jim* to be the traitor when reading the stamp, but he gets suspicious. Then seeing *Jim* alive (and denouncing *Kittridge*, which isn't that believable to *Ethan*, I guess) substantiates the suspicion.

Comment: why would jim brought that bible to work?

Comment: @JimThio Because he had to chat with *Max* from *Prague* so he just brought the bible with him in case, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Well either Max is a liar or the screenwriters didn't understand what they were doing because Max tells Ethan that Job never used script to communicate (so the bible is not needed) and that that's how she new she was dealing with someone else (Ehtan did use bible quotes)